# Convertir query en SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

buenas noches a todos comunidad , por favor necesito una gran ayuda , necesito convertir este query en un SP ,  se esta seleccionando varias tablas y pedí mucha ayuda para poder hacerlo, ahora me falta convertirlo en un SP para luego consumirlo se los agradecería mucho

```
select nt.CUN,
       rb2.IdRubro,
       rb2.DescripcionRubro,
       rb1.IdRubro,
       rb1.DescripcionRubro,
       nt.TotalMoneda1,
       nt.TotalMoneda2,
       cosn.IdRubro2,
       cosn.DescripcionRubro2,
       cosn.TotalMoneda1,
       cosn.TotalMoneda2
from pwt.Nota nt
inner join pwt.CargaDetalle cd
on nt.IdCargaDetalle = cd.IdCargaDetalle 
inner join pwt.Rubro rb1
on nt.IdRubro = rb1.IdRubro
inner join pwt.Rubro rb2
on cd.IdRubro = rb2.IdRubro 
left join (
    select csli.CUN as CUN,
          cni.IdRubro as IdRubro1,
          ru2.DescripcionRubro as DescripcionRubro1,
          csli.IdRubro as IdRubro2,
          ru1.DescripcionRubro as DescripcionRubro2,
          csli.TotalMoneda1 as TotalMoneda1,
          csli.TotalMoneda2 as TotalMoneda2
    from pwt.ConsolidadoSubLineaIndividual csli
    inner join pwt.ConsolidadoNotaIndividual cni
    on csli.IdConsolidadoNo = cni.IdConsolidadoNo
    inner join pwt.ConsolidadoIndividual ci
    on cni.IdConsolidadoIn = ci.IdConsolidadoIn
    inner join pwt.Rubro ru1
    on csli.IdRubro = ru1.IdRubro
    inner join pwt.Rubro ru2
    on cni.IdRubro = ru2.IdRubro
    where ci.IdCabecera = 928
) as cosn 
on nt.IdRubro = cosn.IdRubro1
where cd.IdCabecera IN (928,929) 
order by CUN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es mucho más fácil de lo que parece.

```
Create procedure dbo.nameProcedure
As
Begin 
--- el código
End
```

En tú caso:

```
Create procedure dbo.myProcedure 
As
Begin

Select nt.CUN
     , rb2.IdRubro
     , rb2.DescripcionRubro
     , rb1.IdRubro
     , rb1.DescripcionRubro
     , nt.TotalMoneda1
     , nt.TotalMoneda2
     , cosn.IdRubro2
     , cosn.DescripcionRubro2
     , cosn.TotalMoneda1
     , cosn.TotalMoneda2
       From pwt.Nota As nt
            Inner Join pwt.CargaDetalle As cd On nt.IdCargaDetalle = cd.IdCargaDetalle
            Inner Join pwt.Rubro As rb1 On nt.IdRubro = rb1.IdRubro
            Inner Join pwt.Rubro As rb2 On cd.IdRubro = rb2.IdRubro
            Left Join (
                        Select csli.CUN As CUN
                             , cni.IdRubro As IdRubro1
                             , ru2.DescripcionRubro As DescripcionRubro1
                             , csli.IdRubro As IdRubro2
                             , ru1.DescripcionRubro As DescripcionRubro2
                             , csli.TotalMoneda1 As TotalMoneda1
                             , csli.TotalMoneda2 As TotalMoneda2
                               From pwt.ConsolidadoSubLineaIndividual As csli
                                    Inner Join pwt.ConsolidadoNotaIndividual As cni On csli.IdConsolidadoNo = cni.IdConsolidadoNo
                                    Inner Join pwt.ConsolidadoIndividual As ci On cni.IdConsolidadoIn = ci.IdConsolidadoIn
                                    Inner Join pwt.Rubro As ru1 On csli.IdRubro = ru1.IdRubro
                                    Inner Join pwt.Rubro As ru2 On cni.IdRubro = ru2.IdRubro
                               Where ci.IdCabecera = 928
                      ) As cosn On nt.IdRubro = cosn.IdRubro1
       Where cd.IdCabecera In(928, 929)
       Order By CUN;

End
```